# Minimum oriented bounding rectangle of points in boost geometry

Tags: c++, boost, bounding-box, boost-geometry

In boost geometry, there is an [envelope function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/envelope/envelope.html) that calculates axis-aligned bounding box of the given geometry. Is there any function to calculate the `minimum *oriented* bounding rectangle`(also known as Oriented Bounding Box (OBB)) for a given `list of points` in boost?
There is a solution in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/finding-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points) thread.  But my concern is fast computation for many rectangles.
A fast implementation in c++ also is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Currently (Boost 1.67) OBBs are not supported.

There is convex_hull() function which is used by solutions listed in the thread you mentioned. However you'd have to write the rest of the algorithm by yourself and you wouldn't be able to do anything with the OOB using Boost.Geometry unless it was represented as polygon which would be suboptimal.